# Exporting a pandas Pivittable to excel with aggregation in place

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, pivot-table

I have a data frame called Cars consisting of 3 columns

CarMake, Colour,QtySold

The Data Frame date is in the following format:

```
CarMake. Colour. QtySold
BMW.     Red.     1
BMW.     Red      3
Ford.    Red.     4
Ford.    Black.   1
BMW.     Black    3
```

In Pyhon I have the following code to create a pivot table

```
multi_indexUBS = pd.pivot_table(Cars, index = ['CarMake','Colour'], values = 'QtySold', aggfunc = 'sum')
```

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

```
output in python gives correct result:
CarMake.  Colour. QtySold
BMW.       Red.   4
           Black. 3
Ford.      Red.   4
           Black. 1
```

When I try to export to excel using

Cars.to_excel(export_file_path, index=False, header=True)

the result in excel shows the df data. (lost pivot formatting)

Is it possible to export the Pivot table as displayed in Python(without redoing pivot in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `.reset_index()` in preparation for the next step
2. Use boolean indexing with `.duplicated()` on the `CarMake` column to return `NaN` for repeated values in the `CarMake` column. Then, when you export to excel, it will have the desired output:

---

```
Cars = multi_indexUBS.reset_index()
Cars['CarMake'] = Cars[~Cars['CarMake'].duplicated()]
Cars.to_excel(export_file_path, index=False, header=True)

CarMake    Colour QtySold
BMW        Red          4
NaN        Black        3
Ford       Red          4
NaN         Black       1
```